# Comparar "Ativo" == $objeto->status em PHP

Tags: php

```
$matricula=$_POST['matricula'];

foreach ($aluno as $objeto){

    if ($objeto->matricula==$matricula ) {

        echo $objeto->status;

        if ($objeto->$mail == false and "Ativo" == $objeto->status ) {
            echo "Sua conta foi criado com sucesso";
        } elseif ($objeto->$mail == true) {
            echo "VocÊ já possui email";
        }else{
            echo "Voce está inativo";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse $objeto->$mail realmente é um valor boolean?

Comment: Qual erro você está obtendo? Dê mais detalhes sobre seu problema para que possamos ajudá-lo com mais precisão e facilidade.

Comment: SIm, a comparação que não funciona é essa "Ativo" == $objeto->status

Comment: Se possível coloca ai o retorno da variável $objeto

Comment: A comparação "Ativo" == $objeto->status sempre da false, mesmo se for igual.

Comment: Faz assim echo '<pre>'; var_dump($objeto); die; e coloca aqui o retorno.

Comment: object(Alunos)#7 (6) {
  ["nome"]=>
  string(23) "Gabriela Santos Ribeiro"
  ["matricula"]=>
  string(6) "109647"
  ["telefone"]=>
  string(10) "99999-9955"
  ["mail"]=>
  string(15) "email@gmail.com"
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "Ativo
"     O email n é boolean.

Comment: O valor de status está constando 7 caracteres, enquanto ativo só tem 5, então há caracteres indesejados ali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo seu comentário em sua questão, o valor `$objeto->status` possui um espaço no final ("Ativo "). Logo, você está comparando a string "Ativo" com a string "Ativo " e por isso vem recebendo falso como resultado da expressão.

Para resolver este problema você pode usar a função [trim()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php) para remover este espaço ao fazer a comparação. Tente trocar esta linha:

```
if ($objeto->$mail == false and "Ativo" == $objeto->status ) {
```

por esta:

```
if ($objeto->$mail == false and "Ativo" == trim($objeto->status)) {
```

**Dica:** *utilize também a função [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php) para converter as strings para minúsculo antes de comparar. Isso evite problemas ao comparar "Ativo" com "ativo", por exemplo. Faça assim:*

```
// remove espaços e converte $objeto->status para minúsculo antes de comparar
if ($objeto->$mail == false and "ativo" == strtolower(trim($objeto->status))) {
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ,Funcionou !!!

Comment: @LucasSoares De nada! Que bom que funcionou. Por favor, caso esta resposta tenha resolvido seu problema lembre-se de [aceitá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079) para informar outros usuários que seu problema foi resolvido e ajudar futuros visualizadores da sua questão. Obrigado!